# Merge Two Lists of Data Frames by ID and DATE in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, merge

I need to merge two lists of data frames by two key variables, ID and DATE. Here is an example of the data that I have:

```
 names1 <- c("df1", "df2")
 mydf1 <- data.frame(ID=c(115477, 115477), DATE=c("2012-01-31","2012-02-   29"), SCORE =c(677,635)) 
 mydf2 <- data.frame(ID=c(22319, 22319), DATE=c("2011-09-30","2011-10-31"), SCORE = c(621,630))
 list1 <- list(mydf1,mydf2)
 names(list1) <- names1

 names2 <- c("df_auto1", "df_auto2")
 mydf_auto1 <- data.frame(ID=c(22319, 22319),DATE=c("2011-09-30","2011-10-31") , Fprice =c(8708,8708)) 
 mydf_auto2 <- data.frame(ID=c(115477, 115477), DATE=c("2012-01-31","2012-02-29"), Fprice = c(NA,6543))
 list2 <- list(mydf_auto1,mydf_auto2)
 names(list2) <- names2
```

I tried to use Map function but the output I got is messed up. Here is what I tried to do:

```
 V <-Map(merge, list1, list2,MoreArgs=list(by=c('ID','DATE'), all=TRUE))

 for (i in seq_along(V)) {
 write.csv(V[[i]], paste0("merge_",i, ".csv"))
 }
```

As the final output, I'd like to get one dataframe with ID = 115477 and fully populated variables such as DATE, SCORE and Fprice; another dataframe with ID = 22319 and fully populated as well.  For example, for ID = 115477 I'd like to get:

```
  ID        DATE          SCORE    Fprice
 115477    2012-01-31     677     NA
 115477    2012-02-29     635     6543
```

Does anyone have any idea of what I am doing wrong? Thank you for your help.

Comment: you can try `merge( do.call(rbind, list1), do.call(rbind, list2), by=c('ID', 'DATE'), all=TRUE )`

Comment: Hi chinsoon12, thank you very much for your suggestion. Your solution is perfect! I though have a concern regarding rbind. My data is enormous. rbind command will combine all data frames together. Is there anyway to keep lists of data frames?

Comment: I guess, I"ll go with the following solution: V <- merge(do.call(rbind,list1), do.call(rbind,list2), by=c('ID', 'DATE'),all=TRUE)
out <- split(V, f = V$ID)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Overview

Conduct the [`merge()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html) inside of [`mapply()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/mapply.html).

The end result is a list containing two data frames, each one the result of j<sup>th</sup> element in `list2` being [outer joined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_join) onto the i<sup>th</sup> element in `list1`.

*Note: There was a typo in the second `DATE` element within `mydf1` that is corrected below. My answer depends on the contents of `list1` and `list2` possessing data frames that contain the same `ID` value, in the same order. As the OP has it arranged, `mydf_auto2` is set to be merged onto `mydf1`; whereas `mydf_auto2` should be merged onto `mydf2` based on these two data frames sharing the same `ID` value. I revise the ordering within `list2` to produce the desired output.*

```
# create first list of data frames
names1 <- c("df1", "df2")
# note the extra spacing in "2012-02-29" has been corrected
mydf1 <- data.frame(ID=c(115477, 115477), DATE=c("2012-01-31","2012-02-29"), SCORE =c(677,635)) 
mydf2 <- data.frame(ID=c(22319, 22319), DATE=c("2011-09-30","2011-10-31"), SCORE = c(621,630))
list1 <- list(mydf1,mydf2)
names(list1) <- names1

# create second list of data frames
names2 <- c("df_auto1", "df_auto2")
# here is where I relabel the data frames
# to sync with `mydf1` and `mydf2` based on 
# the `ID` values contained in `mydf_auto1` and `mydf_auto2`
mydf_auto1 <- data.frame(ID=c(115477, 115477), DATE=c("2012-01-31","2012-02-29"), Fprice = c(NA,6543))
mydf_auto2 <- data.frame(ID=c(22319, 22319),DATE=c("2011-09-30","2011-10-31") , Fprice =c(8708,8708)) 
list2 <- list(mydf_auto1,mydf_auto2)
names(list2) <- names2

# merge the list of data frames together
merged.list.of.dfs <-
  mapply( FUN = function( i, j )
    merge( x = i
           , y = j
           , by = c( "ID", "DATE" )
           , all = TRUE )
    , list1
    , list2
    , SIMPLIFY = FALSE )

# view results
merged.list.of.dfs
# $df1
#       ID       DATE SCORE Fprice
# 3 115477 2012-01-31   677     NA
# 4 115477 2012-02-29   635   6543
# 
# $df2
#      ID       DATE SCORE Fprice
# 1 22319 2011-09-30   621   8708
# 2 22319 2011-10-31   630   8708

# end of script #
```

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help me. Your approach is very interesting. However, I"d like to get a slightly different output. I'd like to see a list of dataframes where in df1 (say, ID = 22319) I have both scores and Fprice fully populated.

Comment: @Yelena, please check out my revised answer that delivers your expected output.

Comment: @Yelena thank you! I appreciate you clarifying the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyverse);
list(bind_rows(list1), bind_rows(list2)) %>%
    reduce(function(x, y) full_join(x, y, by = c("ID", "DATE"))) %>%
    filter(ID %in% c(115477))
#      ID       DATE SCORE Fprice
#1 115477 2012-01-31   677     NA
#2 115477 2012-02-29   635   6543
```

Explanation: For each `list` we bind rows into a single `data.frame`; we collect the two collapsed `data.frame`s in a `list` and then perform an outer join by `"ID"` and `"DATE"`; we use `dplyr::filter` to pull out the rows of interest (here `ID==115477`).

Comment: Hi Maurits Evers, thank you very much for suggesting this solution. It does work but I got 6 warning messages while running it. Is it smth that I should worry about? For example, 1: In bind_rows_(x, .id) : Unequal factor levels: coercing to character
2: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
3: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector

Comment: @Yelena The warnings are completely harmless in this case, and can be ignored. They originate from `factor` to `character` conversions when merging. You can avoid them completely, if you construct `data.frame`s with argument `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.

Comment: @Yelena [continued] Alternatively, you can also globally set `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`, which means that in every `data.frame` you create `character` columns will not be converted to `factor`s. `tibbles` (from the `tidyverse`) will never perform this (often undesired) implicit `character` to `factor` conversion. So if you completely work within the `tidyverse` (from data generation to manipulation) the warnings you see would not show up.

Comment: Thank you very, very much. I understand now. It is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier for you to do a `merge`, then separately extract the IDs you want

```
names1 <- c("df1", "df2")
mydf1 <- data.frame(ID=c(115477, 115477), DATE=c("2012-01-31","2012-02-29"), SCORE =c(677,635)) 
mydf2 <- data.frame(ID=c(22319, 22319), DATE=c("2011-09-30","2011-10-31"), SCORE = c(621,630))
# Note the change to use of rbind instead of list
list1 <- rbind(mydf1, mydf2)

names2 <- c("df_auto1", "df_auto2")
mydf_auto1 <- data.frame(ID=c(22319, 22319),DATE=c("2011-09-30","2011-10-31") , Fprice =c(8708,8708)) 
mydf_auto2 <- data.frame(ID=c(115477, 115477), DATE=c("2012-01-31","2012-02-29"), Fprice = c(NA,6543))
list2 <- rbind(mydf_auto1,mydf_auto2)

df <- merge(list1, list2, by = c("ID", "DATE"))
df[df$ID == 115477,]
df[df$ID == 22319, ]
```

Comment: Hi whalea, thank you very much for suggesting this solution. I though got an error message: > K <- merge(list1, list2, by = c("ID", "DATE"))
Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify uniquely valid columns. Any idea of how to fix it?

Comment: @Yelena does both your `list1` and `list2` have the columns `ID` and `DATE`? you can double check this by running `names(list1)` and `names(list2)`. If either of your list does not have both these columns exactly, it will not work

Comment: Yes, both have "ID" and "DATE".

Comment: do you have rows within `list1` where the `ID` and `DATE` are exactly the same? same question for `list2`. Because if that is the case, you would not be able to merge them so directly

Comment: I am currently working with the exact example that is described in this question.